# Notification from background thread in C callback

Tags: objective-c, callback, objective-c++, nsnotifications, coremidi

As my first Mac application, I'm building an app that displays incoming MIDI timecode.
Therefore, I am having an instance of the RtMidi "library" which wraps the MIDI in and out stuff.
The Mac OS Core MIDI callback is in blank C and is called on multiple threads internally. The RtMidi stuff in in C++ and forwards this multi-threaded call to one single (the main) thread.

As I need a Cocoa function to notify other classes that a new MIDI timecode has arrived ( which happens about every 7-9 ms ), I implemented a Singleton which all necessary classes observe.

So, the order in which the functions are called is :

```
    Core MIDI callback -> RtMidi function -> user callback -> Notification ( via Singleton )
```

Basically, this works!

The problem is that I right now have everything on the same thread ( the main thread). If I post a notification from the MIDI callback and the called functions take longer to complete than the above mentioned 7-9 ms, the Core MIDI callback gets blocked which causes the whole application to freeze. 
I tried debugging and it seems that there is some kind of deadlock occurring.

Anyone has some directions on how to implement multithreading in this case?
As I also do UI updating in the notification observers, I would need all notifications to appear on the main thread. What I don't understand is how everything goes with C / C++ / Objective-C in this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that at the stage that you forward your call from your background thread to the main thread that you do so in a non-blocking manner, if possible. For example, you could use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, passing NO for the last argument, or some other mechanism like `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ ... })`. This will prevent your background thread from getting blocked, and allow the UI to be updated whenever it has time to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried around with it a little bit and found out that only the GCD approach, meaning the `dispatch_async(...` is actually working without blocking the app. I was trying to get another queue in the `dispatch_async`mechanism to get the highest possible priority. This did also block the app... Any ideas how I could make sure to have the notification posted immediately? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "immediately"; if you don't block, you can't really get any guarantees about timing beyond "as soon as possible".

Comment: Thanks alot. I guess I will have to try if everything is working out.